# UrlChecker Thread in Selenium causes sun.misc.Unsafe.park on Tomcat context reload

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium, tomcat, selenium-webdriver

When tomcat reloads I get

```
WARNING: The web application [myapp] appears to have started a thread  named [UrlChecker-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The only to way solve it I could think of is:

```
    Set<Thread> threads = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
    for (Thread t : threads) {
        System.out.println("Thread: " + t.getName() + " " + t.getClass().getName());
        String name = t.getName();
        if (name.contains("UrlChecker")) {
            System.out.println("Interrupting thread " + name + " " + t.getState());
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            t.interrupt();
            t.join();
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long diff = (end - start) / 1000;
            System.out.println("Time diff " + diff);
        }
    }
```

This is far from ideal, not only I am doing a search using a magic string of 'UrlChecker', I am also interrupting a TIMED_WAITING thread what forces me to wait 60s before the shutting down logic resumes.

The thread is started from a private static Executor. The UrlChecker class can be viewed here:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/net/UrlChecker.java

I have raised this with Selenium guys: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2716

Comment: This concerns me also. The static final thread pool isn't getting shutdown with contextDestroyed. Will it eventually die and be collected? I don't know. The general wisdom says to explicitly shut down thread pools in contextDestroyed.